# Interpret coefficient in log$_{10}$-linear model

Tags: data-transformation, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I have a doubt. I had to normalize the errors transforming the dependent variable into $\log_{10},$ so I have an equation of this form:

$$\log y = 2.49 - 0.0006X_1 + 0.0328X_2;$$

also the variable $X_2$ is data in percentage ($1$ to $100$). Now I want to vary the variable $X_2;$ how would I interpret this?

I tried with this equality $\ln y = 2.3026\log y$ since most bibliographies work with $\ln,$ but doing this, the results of my dependent variable are modified.

Is it possible to transform it back into an equation of the form $Y = a + b_1 x_1 + b_2x_2? $

Comment: Wehn transforming back, you must use the exponential function (with base 10 in your case). According to the ruls $10^{x+y}=10^x\cdot 10^y$, the addition becomes a multiplication in the backtransformed model.

Comment: Since $\log$ can refer either to $\ln$ or $\log_{10}$ depending on context, can you please adjust the notation in your question to its more explicit form.  (I'm assuming you mean that latter, but it would be helpful to be explicit.)

Answer (score 1):

##### Your *variables* do not change --- only the *coefficients* change

You presently have a regression equation of the form:

$$\log_{10}(\hat{y}) = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 x_2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\hat{y} = 10^{\hat{\beta}_0} \times (01^{\hat{\beta}_1})^{x_1} \times (10^{\hat{\beta}_2})^{x_2}.$$

You can convert this model form to any logarithmic-base $r$ by using $\log_{r}(y) = 
\log_{r}(10) \cdot \log_{10}(y)$.  To convert to the natural logarithm we take $r=e$ and define new coefficient parameters ${\alpha}_i \equiv \ln(10) {\beta}_i$  and their corresponding estimators $\hat{\alpha}_i \equiv \ln(10) \hat{\beta}_i$, which yields the equivalent converted model form:

$$\ln(\hat{y}) = \hat{\alpha}_0 + \hat{\alpha}_1 x_1 + \hat{\alpha}_2 x_2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\hat{y} = e^{\hat{\alpha}_0} \times (e^{\hat{\alpha}_1})^{x_1} \times (e^{\hat{\alpha}_2})^{x_2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use simple $\log$ rules to transform into the natural logarithm. Change of base is $\log_b(y)=\frac{\log_a(y)}{\log_a(b)}$ and hence $\log_{10}(y)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(10)}$ and you can write
$$\ln(y)=\ln(10)\cdot(2.49 - 0.0006X_1 + 0.0328X_2)=5.73344-0.00138X_1+0.075523X_2$$

which is easier to swallow. That's part 1.

Part 2 is the concept of a [link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function). In many regression models, the output variable $\hat{y}_i$ is **not** equal to the linear predictor $\hat{\theta}_i=\hat{\beta}^Tx_i$ but rather some transformation, i.e $\hat{y}_i=g\left(\hat{\theta}_i\right)$. This $g$ function is called the *link function*, which allows us to convert the output variable from $\mathbb{R}$ to the relevant support. In classic linear regression, $g$ is the identity function, but that is not always the case: for example, in logistic regression the output variable is a probability and thus $g$ is the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) which satisfies $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$. In Poisson regression, however, the output is an integer so a very common link function is the exponential: $\hat{y}_i=\exp\left(\hat{\theta}_i\right)$ which can be equivalently written as $\ln(y_i)=\hat{\beta}^Tx_i$. I think this looks familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation. one last consultation. I understand that the coefficient in X2 if it is less than 0.15 (which is my case) is simply multiplied by 100 and I interpret the result as the percentage variation in Y, this means that every time it varies by 1 to X2 then Y varies by 7.55%? over there I saw that it is no longer necessary to multiply by 100 since my variable was already entered into the model in percentage values (0 to 100)? And if I had any bibliography of the transformation (first and second part) that you just showed me, I would be very grateful.